# Adding Vendor lookup to custom field

Tags: acumatica

I added a custom field for vendorid on the SO Line. (Yes, I know there is one there, but we are building some new logic). I've added the integer field and it appears on the grid fine. I'm trying to get a lookup of vendors. I started with this

```
Where<AP.Vendor.type, NotEqual<BAccountType.employeeType>>>))]
```

and then tried

```
    Where<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.companyType>, 
        Or<AP.Vendor.type, NotEqual<BAccountType.employeeType>>>>), 
    Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, CacheGlobal = true, Filterable = true)]
```

It got me a lookup on new records, but then when I save and try to open any sales order, I get an error that says *"Error: An error occurred during the processing of the field InventoryID: Specified cast is not valid.."* which makes no sense to me. But if I remove the above it works, so seems like that must be the issue.

Stack Trace as requested:
Error:  Error: An error occurred during processing of the field InventoryID: Specified cast is not valid..

```
    Raised At: 2/24/2020 6:47:58 PM     Screen: SO.30.10.00         

Details:
2/24/2020 6:47:58 PM Error:
Error: An error occurred during processing of the field InventoryID: Specified cast is not valid..

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
   at PX.Data.PXDataRecord.GetInt32(Int32 i)
   at PX.Data.PXDBIntAttribute.RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowSelecting(Object item, PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly)
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowSelecting(Object item, PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Select(PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly, Boolean& wasUpdated)
   at PX.Data.PXView.GetResult(Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, Boolean reverseOrder, Int32 topCount, PXSearchColumn[] sorts, Boolean& overrideSort, Boolean& extFilter)
   at PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)
   at PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry.transactions()
   at _CustomMethod(Object , Object[] )
   at PX.Data.PXView.InvokeDelegate(Object[] parameters)
   at PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Could you add a stack trace for the error? It may shed some light on the error. Full field definition may help as well

Comment: `[PXDBInt]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Vendor ID")]
[AP.Vendor(typeof(Search<BAccountR.bAccountID,
Where<AP.Vendor.type, NotEqual<BAccountType.employeeType>>>))]`

Comment: Are you sure this is the only thing that can cause the issue? Maybe there is something else.

Comment: Well, if I take that off, it works fine. If I add it then it fails. I thought maybe my code so I purged all the code out of that customization and just published that one and I still get the problem.

Comment: So, so fun I took off all the customizations and then added a field to the poorder table with the same attributes. Same error. It's something about that lookup that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

Remove PXDBInt attribute from the field.

---

The issue here is not with `Where` condition but with attributes definition for the field.

```
 [PXDBInt]  
 [PXUIField(DisplayName="Vendor ID")] 
 [AP.Vendor(typeof(Search<BAccountR.bAccountID, Where<AP.Vendor.type,
 NotEqual<BAccountType.employeeType>>>))]
```

Actually, here you have `DBField` attribute twice. You have `PXDBIntAttribute` and `Vendor` attribute that contains `PXDBIntAttribute` inside.
[image]

Because of that the framework has the wrong fields to db columns mapping resulting in that strange error.

If you use Visual studio, I recommend you to try Acuminator extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Acumatica.Acuminator

It highlights that type of errors
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but more of a suggestion than an "answer".  Try building your own PXSelector.  I have a custom DAC that needs to store two vendors, and I had to abandon the AP.Vendor attribute for a custom PXSelector for mine to work.  This is one of mine.  In my case, I need to be able to see which one is defined as the Preferred Vendor for the warehouse, and I only want to see vendors associated with my InventoryID.  SSINItemBranch is a custom DAC that is also available in the scope of this DAC's usage.  The point is, use this as an example if you need one to try creating your own from scratch.  If this isn't how you want to accomplish the task, at least you might isolate if the problem is a use case of the AP.Vendor attribute or something else.

```
[PXSelector(
        typeof(Search2<
            Vendor.bAccountID,
            InnerJoin<POVendorInventory,
                On<POVendorInventory.vendorID, Equal<Vendor.bAccountID>,
                And<POVendorInventory.inventoryID, Equal<Current<SSINItemBranch.inventoryID>>>>,
            LeftJoin<INItemSite, On<INItemSite.inventoryID, Equal<POVendorInventory.inventoryID>,
                And<INItemSite.preferredVendorID, Equal<POVendorInventory.vendorID>,
                And<INItemSite.preferredVendorLocationID, Equal<POVendorInventory.vendorLocationID>,
                And<INItemSite.preferredVendorOverride, Equal<True>>>>>>>,
                Where<Vendor.type, Equal<BAccountType.vendorType>>>),
        typeof(Vendor.acctCD),
        typeof(Vendor.acctName),
        typeof(POVendorInventory.vendorLocationID),
        typeof(INItemSite.preferredVendorOverride),
        typeof(POVendorInventory.vendorInventoryID),
        typeof(POVendorInventory.vLeadTime),
        SubstituteKey = typeof(Vendor.acctCD),
        DescriptionField = typeof(Vendor.acctName),
        Filterable = true
        )]
```